# add a select all option to Jquery Chosen AngularJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to add a select all option to chosen. For some reason I'm only able to select the next option yet to be selected, not all of them. Any ideas?

```
 // select all chosen
    $(document).on('click', '.group-result', function() { //modify this to be based off of superheroes
        var unselected = $(this).nextUntil('.group-result').not('.result-selected');
        if(unselected.length) {
            unselected.trigger('mouseup'); //bug - only selects one at a time
        }
    });
```